# Using C# Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel but Getting error Could not load file Version=15.0.0.0

Tags: c#, excel, office365, office-interop, office-automation

Trying to import the data from an Excel sheet into a Sql Server table. The code is activated by a button in a userform. But I am getting the error below when clicking it. I am using a work machine and we have Microsoft Excel 365. I have read this can be an issue, but is the below saying it cannot find the interop file? I've read around but I cannot workout which answers relate to my specific issue.

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'office, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c'. The system cannot find the file specified.
> File name: 'office, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c'

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

namespace FormSqlInsertCsv
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnImport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlApp;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook xlWorkbook;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet xlWorksheet;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range xlRange;

            int xlRow;
            string strFileName;

            openFD.Filter = "Excel Office |*.xls; *xlsx";
            openFD.ShowDialog();
            strFileName = openFD.FileName;

            if(strFileName != "")
            {
                xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
                xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(strFileName);
                xlWorksheet = (Worksheet)xlWorkbook.Worksheets["Sheet1"];
                //xlRange = xlWorksheet.UsedRange;
                xlRange = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)xlWorksheet.UsedRange;

                int i = 0;

                for(xlRow = 2; xlRow <= xlRange.Rows.Count; xlRow++)
                {
                    i++;
                    dgvEmployees.Rows.Add(i, xlRange.Cells[xlRow, 1].ToString(), xlRange.Cells[xlRow, 2].ToString(), xlRange.Cells[xlRow, 3].ToString(), xlRange.Cells[xlRow, 4].ToString(), xlRange.Cells[xlRow, 5].ToString(), xlRange.Cells[xlRow, 6].ToString());

                }
                xlWorkbook.Close();
                xlApp.Quit();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: office inter-op only compatible with dot net 4.8

Comment: search for interop.excel and install the nuget

Comment: Thanks. I had already downloaded interop.excel from nuget. I am running visual studio 2022 which uses .net 6.0. Can you advise please.

Comment: no way Microsoft stopped support bundling office.interop with dot net 3.1, 5, 6, if you want to use office.interop you have to use dot net 4.8, and if you want to use dot net 6 then use ClosedXML https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML library to create excel files, Which is wrapper of OpenXML https://github.com/OfficeDev/Open-XML-SDK , ClosedXML is nice and easy and fast(Even easier then office.interop), OpenXML very steep learning curve

Comment: Sorry! do you have office 2016 or higher installed on your machine. just realized i am using Office.Interop with dot net  6 in one of my project, and i faced the same kind of error and solution was, that i have to install office 2019 on my development machine. AND ONE MORE THING WITH Office.Interop YOU HAVE TO INSTALL OFFICE ON CLIENT MACHINE TOO TO MAKE IT WORK, so it is best to go with ClosedXML

Comment: Thank you! I am using Excel 365.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on references and add Office.dll reference from the following location C/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/office/15.0.0.0__71e9bce111e9429c/Office.dll

Comment: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Office